# Rate of convergance of integral of fourier series

Tags: real-analysis

The coefficients of Fourier series are constant. Upon integrating the Fourier series expression as the usual sum of sines and cosines, over one full period, what can you deduce?

From my understanding, integration the sines and cosines are 0 and only the constant term will remain. The question is to be answered by talking about the convergence of the integral with respect to the original Fourier series. Even if I just write the integral without making it 0 yet, I'm still confused about the constant 1/n term that appears after the integration and its significance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think question is comparison of rate of convergence of original series with the rate of convergence of series of integrals.